# How to quickly de-select all build targets except for the one you want in xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to deselect all build targets quickly and then select only the one I care about. This is in the edit schema -> Build part. Normally I'd go through by hand to deselect each one but there's over 600 test targets and build them all takes an extremely long time.

[image: swift]

Any ideas how best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do opposite thing - instead of disable all to run one, just open `Test navigator` and run one test-target explicitly, as shown below

[image: demo]